# Why Method reference is compatible to a functional interface with difference number of args?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

I understand that method reference can be used to implement a functional interface if the referred method takes the same number of args as the functional interface and return the same type, but why in some cases the referred method has different number of args than the functional interface but are still compatible?

I have a simple BiConsumer that I try to use method reference to implement it. I know I can use lambda expression also as long as the number of args matches. I will show the code to explain it clearly.

I have a `BiConsumer<ArrayList<String>, ? super String>` that I want to implement.

Lambda expression way to do that is:

`BiConsumer<ArrayList<String>, ? super String> b = (firstArg,secondArg) -> firstArg.add(secondArg);` since they both takes 2 input args, there is no problem.

But why `BiConsumer<ArrayList<String>, ? super String> a = ArrayList::add;` is also compatible? The `add` method on ArrayList only takes 1 input args but the functional interface needs 2.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The first argument is the arraylist to call `add` on

Comment: Because it's making use of the list itself in the reference. I forget the specific name for it, but you can resolve these references either to something which is invoked on the first argument or simply gets the first argument passed in later. e.g. `myInstance::foo(int)` and `MyClass::foo(MyClass, int)` can both be resolved to fit a `BiConsumer<MyClass, Integer>`

Comment: @Progman I know that, but I think it's referencing to the 1 arg add() since the other add(Integer index, String something) takes an Integer and a string but my BiConsumer doesn't define any Integer

Comment: @khelwood yeah, I kinda figured it out how it works by looking at my lambda solution but why is it allowed? Doesn't the reference method should have the same args as the functional interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ### [15.12.2.1. Identify Potentially Applicable Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1)
>
> A method reference expression (§15.13) is potentially compatible with a functional interface type `T` if, where the arity of the function type of `T` is `n`, there exists at least one potentially applicable method when the method reference expression targets the function type with arity `n` (§15.13.1), and one of the following is true:
>
> - The method reference expression has the form `ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier` and at least one potentially applicable method is either (i) static and supports arity `n`, **or (ii) not static and supports arity `n-1`**.

The function type you want to use has arity 2

```
void accept(T t, U u);
```

and the method `ArrayList::add` refers to has arity 1, and it's not static. It makes it potentially applicable.

Comment: How did you learn spring? I am trying to learn spring but failed so far. I need your help. Can you provide me with some resource to learn it? I really need help. I want to learn to create a website in spring @Andrew Tobilko

Comment: @Pie I am a supporter of official sources. I usually read their documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/index.html). It's good for both beginners and experienced developers.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am looking for. So it's totally valid even the arity does not match.

Answer (score 6):

The first argument is the ArrayList to call `add` on.

In this case,

```
ArrayList::add
```

means

```
(list, obj) -> list.add(obj)
```

which is a BiConsumer.

Comment: yeah, I kinda figured it out how it works by looking at my lambda solution but why is it allowed? Doesn't the reference method should have the same args as the functional interface? If the functional interface is defined as `BiConsumer<String, String>`, then I pass a method reference to a 1 arg method, it shows compiler error.

Comment: It's an instance method, so one of the arguments it *must* have is an instance to call it on. It would be impossible to use `ArrayList::add` if you didn't supply an ArrayList to it.

Comment: so you mean when the compiler see the method reference, it knows this is an instance method, so it will try to apply the first argument as the instance and then call the method by passing the second argument to it? This looks like a specific type of method reference when the method is an instance method on one (or any argument)

Comment: "when the compiler see the method reference, it knows this is an instance method, so it will try to apply the first argument as the instance" -- Yes

Comment: I think the first argument is called the *receiver* in this context.